# No suitable constructor found for ImageView(no arguments)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, constructor, imageview

I'm running an app that gets multiple images for view after picking them or capturing them. When I run the app there seems to be a problem with the ImageView part it says:

Error:(41, 25) error: no suitable constructor found for ImageView(no arguments)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context,AttributeSet,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

How to resolve this?
I got the error on line 14 ivImage=new ImageView(); saying cannot find symbol variable ivimage

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean zoomOut = false;
int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
Button btnSelect;


LinearLayout root ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    ivImage=new ImageView();
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

    ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
}
```

Comment: *Where* is the error? On that first line, or somewhere else? You haven't shown any code calling an `ImageView` constructor without any arguments...

Comment: @JonSkeet the code is: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean zoomOut = false;
    int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    Button btnSelect;
    ImageView ivImage = new ImageView();
It's the last statement ImageView ivImage = new ImageView();

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the answer

Comment: In the code you originally posted you wrote `new ImageView( this )`.  Wouldn't that work?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the following line:

```
ImageView ivImage = new ImageView();
```

as [`ImageView` does not have a zero-argument constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Comment: I then I got the error on line 14 ivImage=new ImageView(); saying cannot find symbol variable ivimage

Comment: @AhmedEl-Shafei: I am going to assume that you really mean `ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);`, as I told you to get rid of `ivImage=new ImageView();`. Change `ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);` to `ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);`.

Comment: It worked thank you :)) I just have another problem when I'm running the app it getting me a white blank page on my mobile do you have any idea why?